# Backbone Collection mutator to reference in template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, ecmascript-6, marionette

Is there a way using `Backbone.js`/`Marionette` to use mutators similar to how they're used in a `Model`, but on a `Collection`? For example:

In `MyCollection.js`:

```
export default Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MyModel,
    ...
    mutators: {
        foo: function() {
            if (this.models.length)
                return this.models[0].get('foo');
            return "default value";
        }
    }
})
```

Then in `MyModel.js`:

```
export default Backbone.Model.extend({
    mutators: {
        foo: function() {
            return "bar";
        }
    }
})
```

And in `template.ejs`:

```
<div>
    <h1><%= myCollection.foo %></h1>
    <% for (var myModel of myCollection) { %>
        <span><%= myModel.foo %></span>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

I seem to be getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined` errors, so I'm wondering if this is possible or if there is an alternate method? I would like to avoid moving `MyCollection.foo` logic into templates but that seems to be the easiest method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, mutators is not part of backbone or marionette. It seems you are using [Backbone.Mutators](https://github.com/asciidisco/Backbone.Mutators) plugin. And it's supposed to be used with models rather than collections.

There are many problems with your code. First of all the following code is not valid

```
foo: {
        if (this.models.length)
            return this.models[0].get('foo');
        return "default value";
    }
```

Second you are trying to access properties from the constructors of collection and model.
You should create their instances with data and access model instances from collection instance's `models` property.

```
<div>
  <h1><%= myCollection.foo %></h1>
  <% for (var myModel of myCollection.models) { %>
      <span><%= myModel.get("foo") %></span>
  <% } %>
</div>
```

I doubt if they work with collection since I don't see any examples with collection in the documentation.

Please read the documentation of the plugin and framework you're using and try to understand what you're doing...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I made some typos trying to transfer over and generalize my code. I was under the impression that `Mutators` was a default plugin, but I'm fairly new to Backbone/ Marionette and the code base I'm working in. You're correct that there are examples provided with Mutators on Collections.

Comment: @Tom and 1 more thing, I believe `myModel.foo` should be `myModel.get("foo")` in the underscore template

Answer (score 0):

It appears `Collection`s are not supported by the [Backbone.Mutators](https://github.com/asciidisco/Backbone.Mutators) plugin. It seems the easiest alternative is to just add an `Object` to the `serializeData` method of a `Marionette.View`, i.e:

```
serializeData: function() {
    return { models: this.collection.models, foo: this.collection.foo().toJSON() };
}
```

Here `Mutators` are not even necessary, `foo` is just a function in `MyCollection`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have views to handle templates and render. 
Marionette has a CollectionView api which is probably what you are looking for,
https://marionettejs.com/docs/master/marionette.collectionview.html#rendering-collectionviews
Quote from documentation:

> The CollectionView will loop through all of the models in the
>   specified collection, render each of them using a specified childView,
>   then append the results of the child view's el to the collection
>   view's el. By default the CollectionView will maintain a sorted
>   collection's order in the DOM. This behavior can be disabled by
>   specifying {sort: false} on initialize.